# Как исправить ошибку после обновления страницы (react-douter-dom)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx, react-router-dom

Пытаюсь сделать маршруты с помощью react-router-dom и столкнулся с проблемой что что если я даю двойной путь(/list/:name) то при переходе всё загружается, но если обновить страницу то я получаю ошибку(скриншот ошибки: https://ibb.co/XpNSSYC). Если даю просто(/:name)всё работает хорошо. В чём может быть проблема?
Routes

```
<Switch>
   <Route exact path="/list/:name" children={<ChooseListFilm />} />
</Switch>
```

Header

```
<ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/list/popular">Popular</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/list/top_rated">Top rated</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/list/upcoming">Upcoming</Link>
        </li>
</ul>
```

ChooseListFilm

```
export default function ChooseListFilm() {
    let {name} = useParams();
  return (
        <ListFilms  
          filmType={name}
        />
  );
}
```

ListFilm

//Здесь я получаю список фильмов по API и вывожу их

Comment: Самостоятельно не хотите исправить опечатку и мое исправление отклонили, хлопаю стоя.